# Error in ASP.NET MVC 4 with Universal Providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, sql-server-ce

I created a fresh simple ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Project, then I have created models with the ADO.NET Entity Data Model designer and then I have installed **System.Web.Providers** (Universal Providers) and configured Web.config in order to have two different data sources, both using **SQL CE 4.0**.

These are my connection strings:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=C:\maindb.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
<add name="MyEntitiesModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyEntitiesModel.csdl|res://*/MyEntitiesModel.ssdl|res://*/MyEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=C:\myentities.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The application works. But when I try to login, this is the exception I get:

***To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".***

I have also added `<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />` in Web.config because someone on different forums solved the problem doing this. It wasn't my case, the same error remains.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Just curious, why did you install Universal Providers? SimpleMembership is setup by default in MVC 4 now. Universal Providers is to provide the ability for legacy ASP.NET Membership to work in Azure as well as Session. Why did you install it? :)

Comment: I'd like to use SQL Compact Edition to manage memberships! :)

Comment: As in, you specifically want ASP.NET Membership? MVC 4 (out of the box with the Internet template) uses the new SimpleMembership, which works fine with SQL Compact. You don't need Universal Providers. I'm the PM for both btw. :P

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC4 ships with simple membership, and simple membership works with SQL CE out of the box, you don't need (and in fact can't use) the universal providers with Simple Membership.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1661378.aspx/1) ASP.NET forum post:

> Thanks for the hint.  Now that I was able to see that the provider was
>   being hijacked, I added

```
<appSettings>     
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

> Everything Seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Sorry, I had not wrapped <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" /> between the "CODE" tags here on Stackoverflow so you were not able to see the last piece of text I had written.